# Where does "vmunix" label in syslog come from on Debian/Linux systems?

Tags: linux, debian, syslog

After upgrading one Debian server from Squeeze I noticed that the kernel log messages (those using `kern.*` in `/etc/syslogd.conf`) now appear with "vmunix" prefix while earlier they had "kernel" prefix. This broke some of log monitoring scripts and while it wasn't difficult to fix, I'm now curious about the reason of this change as I can't find any place where this is configured.

Does anybody know where does "vmunix" come from and how could I change it back to "kernel" if I wanted (or are there any good reasons not to do it?)?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the vmunix tag is coming from inetutils-syslogd.  Perhaps changed in the upstream source?

I would expect that you can revert to the kernel tag by using one of the other syslogd daemons. (rsyslogd if it is available on wheeze?).

Comment: Thank you, `vmunix` is indeed hard-coded in [intetutils-syslogd itself](https://github.com/Distrotech/inetutils/blob/4f42626b4cbce429b267f5db06654881f3d741e6/src/syslogd.c#L1029). The trouble is that this line is there from the initial revision back from 1996, so I still don't know why did this change...